# How to programmatically detect how many posts are displayed per page?

Tags: plugins, options

Part of a custom post type that I am building needs to simulate page 1 of a category archive. How can I found out how many posts are displayed per page across the WordPress installation? (I assume it is in `wp_options` but I cannot find it.) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option is appropriately named `posts_per_page`. FYI you can see the value of options in your database by visiting `wp-admin/options.php`.